# Calculate Mean on Multiple Groups

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a Table

```
Sex     Value1   Value2    City
M       2        1         Berlin
W       3        5         Paris
W       1        3         Paris
M       2        5         Berlin
M       4        2         Paris
```

I want to calculate the average of `Value1` and `Value2` for different groups. In my origial Dataset I have 10 Group variables (with a max of 5 characteristics like 5 Cities) that I have shortened to `Sex` and `City` (2 Characteristics) in this example. The result should look like this

```
       AvgOverall   AvgM    AvgW    AvgBerlin    AvgParis
Value1 2,4          2,6     2       2            2,66   
Value2 3,2          2,6     4       3            3,3
```

I am familiar with the `group by` and tried

```
df.groupby('City').mean()
```

But here we have the problem that `Sex` is getting also into the calculation. Does anyone has an idea how to solve this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can grouping by 2 columns to 2 dataframes and then use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) also with means of numeric columns (non numeric are excluded):

```
df1 = df.groupby('City').mean().T
df2 = df.groupby('Sex').mean().T

df3 = pd.concat([df.mean().rename('Overall'), df2, df1], axis=1).add_prefix('Avg')
print (df3)
        AvgOverall      AvgM  AvgW  AvgBerlin  AvgParis
Value1         2.4  2.666667   2.0        2.0  2.666667
Value2         3.2  2.666667   4.0        3.0  3.333333
```